# Use jQuery to navigate data in a <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="teams league">
        <span class="team"><a>Team A</a> <span>at</span></span> 
        <span class="team"><a>Team B</a> </span>
        <div>
            <span>7:00 pm EDT</span>
        </div> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span></span>
                <div>
                    <span>-124</span>
                    <span>+113</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span></span>
                <div>
                    <span>-140</span>
                    <span>+120</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span></span>
                <div>
                    <span>-124</span>
                    <span>+113</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <span></span>
              <div>
                  <span>-125</span>
                  <span>+115</span>
                  <!-- These are the two data I'm trying to pull out. --!>
              </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

There are several such `<tr>` on the page, denoted with the alternating classes `odd` and `even` Okay, so I have the team name stored in a variable, call it `teamName`. I want to find the overarching `<tr>` where one of the two teams (Team A and Team B) is equal to `teamName`. Then, if that exists, I want to get the fifth and final set of data in the `<span>` tags (I've commented in the HTML where that is). I know I need a jQuery selector to fire through these, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ8NB/5/) I've been playing with to try to make some headway. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I tried something like: `$(".team:contains("' + teamName + '")).parent().last("td").text();` but that didn't work.

Comment: Your jsFiddle only shows a couple variables and an alert. Did you post the wrong link? Include what you've tried directly in the question.

Comment: no i just didn't want to put a failed query in fiddle. updated though

Comment: `.parent().siblings().last().text()` would have worked. The `.last()` method doesn't work as you're using it, which you'll discover upon reading the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `:contains` to accomplish this.  Here's a very basic example:

```
$('tr:contains(' + teamName + ')')
```

To get the last span in a single step, you'd add:

```
$('tr:contains(' + teamName + ') span:last')
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zZ8NB/6/

Comment: awesome, this does it, i'll accept when i can. one more question, is there an easy way to also grab that second to last span (in another selector)?

Comment: Yep, you can use the `:nth-last-child()` selector: https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this code greatly, but this does the trick:

```
$(".teams").find(".team").find("a").each(function () {
    var row;
    if ($(this).text() === teamName) {
        row = $(this).closest("tr");
        row.find("td").last().find("div").find("div").find("span").each(function () {
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```